# Having issue changing TLSv1 to TLSv1.2 using SSLContext

Tags: java, ssl, soap, salesforce

I am trying to enable **TLSv1.2** using **SSLContext** and i tried **System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2")**. I am want to enable it for salesforce soap API in my application. The issue is when i run my sample code the TLS version is **TLSv1** so i use my code and change it to **TLSv1.2**. My sample code.

```
 public static void tls(String tls){
    SSLContext context;

      try {
        System.out.println(SSLContext.getDefault().getProtocol());
        context = SSLContext.getInstance(tls);
        context.init(null, null, null);
        System.out.println(SSLContext.getDefault().getProtocol());
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", tls);
        SSLContext.setDefault(context);
        System.out.println(SSLContext.getDefault().getProtocol());
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
}`
```

After changing TLSv1 to TLSv1.2 when i hit salesforce Soap API its uses TLSv1 which salesforce rejects as i have disable TLSv1 on my salesforce account. My salesfoce connection code

```
public static void login(){
    try {

         System.out.println("login()"+SSLContext.getDefault().getProtocol());
         String username = "userName";
         String password = "pass";
         String authEndPoint = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/8.0/";
         SoapBindingStub binding = null;
         binding = (SoapBindingStub)new SforceServiceLocator().getSoap();
         binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, authEndPoint);
         LoginResult rs = null;
         rs = binding.login(username, password);
         GetUserInfoResult userInfo =rs.getUserInfo();
         binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, rs.getServerUrl());
         } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

My Salesforce account login activity logs.

> Failed: Login over insecure channel-SOAP-Partner-8.0-login.salesforce.com-TLS 1.0

I tried every thing i find on google but the issue remain the same. Help me out with this.

Comment: you might be better off posting this on the dedicated salesforce stackexchange (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: anyway, did you find a solution for this? In the SFDC examples usually they connect to a more recent API. What happens if you change 8.0 to e.g. 32.0?

Comment: I tested this by my code but still same error.

Comment: I got no solution yet for this problem